# authentication multi-user angularjs with firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I work on a web-mobile application with angularjs and firebase and I was able to perform a simple authentication with angularjs and firebase, except that in my system I have several types of users and in function each must be redirected to its view. could have more details on how to do it? thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of simple. To improve performance, first load all of user from firebase to `$rootScope` first as array object type. Then, get key-in data from login form and filter with that array object type.

Here is how to populate data from firebase into AngularJS.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var wmApp = angular.module('wmApp');

    wmApp.controller('loginCtrl', LoginCtrl);
    LoginCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$window','$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', '$q'];
    function LoginCtrl($scope, $http, $rootScope, $window, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $q) {
        /* Fuck ya, get KYC operator users from Firebase */
        function getKYCUsers() {
            $scope.showLoading = true;
            var ref = firebase.database().ref().child($rootScope.firebaseUserNode);
            var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
            list.$loaded().then((x) => {
                x.forEach(user => {
                    $rootScope.authenticatedUsers.push(user.username);
                });
            }).catch(() => {

            });
        }

    }
})();
```

Comment: thank you, I'm finishing a demo put on github for more help and I share the link

Comment: Hello here is what I could already have https://github.com/patbi/seedocauth

but I would also like 
1 - to redirect each type of users on his page
2 - Restrict access to the cat view for patients and visitors, but only accessible to doctors